# How to create a descriptive table with a percentage row?

Tags: row, stata, percentage

i am currently working on a comparison of one-parent and two-parent household children regarding their marriage and divorce behavior.
Therefore i wanted to add a descriptive table to my study showing up all the important variables i want to use. But i couldnt manage to add any percentage to my table.
Additionally, is there maybe a way to combine both households into one table?
I hope someone can help me out! Thanks.

I used the code:

```
asdoc sum age agewedcr agewed marcohrt divbest educ hrs2 childs madeg padeg if households == 1, dec(2) 
asdoc sum age agewedcr agewed marcohrt divbest educ hrs2 childs madeg padeg if households == 2, dec(2)
```

Comment: I suggest using the `table1` available from SSC which you can obtain by typing `ssc install table1`. You can then specify to perform the table `by(households)`. You could also try the `baselinetable` package, which has simpler syntax but less pretty output (IMO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine both the tables using the `bys()` prefix with the asdoc command. However, you shall still not get percentages. Recently, I added table1 template to [asdocx](https://fintechprofessor.com/asdocx/) that can report percentages and many other statistics.

Here are some key features of the table1 template:

1. You can control the statistics used with binary, categorical , and continuous variables.
2. You can control the test (ttest, Chi2, etc) used with each type of variables.
3. The template can be used with and without survey weights.
4. Binary variables can be treated as categorical variables or continuous variables.
5. Percentages can be based on row total, column total or grand total
6. The output can be sent to .docx, .xlsx, or .tex format.

Here is a sample code and output from table1 template

```
    asdocx tab vision denied police discouraged ///
    i.fired eds bskin wskin disc , template(table1) 
    replace
```

[Sample Output from table1 template of asdocx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueW4N.jpg)

Comment: Thank you so so much!